# problem with .htaccess and a rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am redirecting a domain in the format [www.mydomain.co](http://www.mydomain.co) or mydomain.co to mysd.herokuapp.com/public/index.html and it works great.  But, I want the url in the browser to show the initial format of [www.mydomain.co](http://www.mydomain.co) or mydomain.co so I added a .htaccess file with the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysd.herokuapp.com/public
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mydomain.co/$1 [P]
```

Now, this is the same rule I use on another domain and it works correctly and shows the initial url, but for some reason on the other site it does not work.

Both sites are hosted on Heroku.  The only difference is where the domain names are registered.

1. Can anyone explain to me why it would work on one domain and not the other?
2. Do I have the rewrite rule wrong?
3. Is there something about the DNS records that would be the issue?  Since the domains are registered at different locations the redirect is set up slightly different. On uses domain forwarding at godaddy, the other user a url redirect record.

Thanks for clarification and help.

Comment: This does not really make sense. If "mydomain.co" is the _old_ domain, then why do you specify it as the _target_ of that proxy  rule? The rule you implemented is the wrong way 'round.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question this is your situation:

You have an old domain "mydomain.co" and moved your content to heroku, so your actual new URL is "mysd.herokuapp.com". You want to go on using the old domain name and proxy requests such that the content from heroku is published via the old domain name.

You can do that using the apache proxy module. But that module needs to be loaded and activated inside the http server serving "mydomain.co".

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ https://mysd.herokuapp.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

This assumes that the structure of your content is identical on both system.

If you serve both domains from the same http server you need to add a condition to prevent a proxy loop:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydoain\.co$
RewriteRule ^ https://mysd.herokuapp.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Consider however the performance penalty you pay for such approach. You need to wait a full second request round for each and every request you handle this way. That will make your content be served sluggish. Sure that is what you want?

Comment: Ok, I follow that, but I have no content at my domain.co.  It is only registered at the registrar and I have set up a domain forward record.  The content is only hosted at heroku.  So I thought with a rewrite rule, I could browse to olddomain.co and via the redirection record at the registrar it would forward to heroku where the rewrite rule would fire and the url at the top of the browser would show the 'nicer' olddomain.co url.  BTW, it really is not an 'old' domain.  It is the current domain, we just have the content hosted at heroku for the time being.

Comment: You don't need any content as such on "mydomain.co". You certainly can forward requests to heroku. The question is what those forwarded requests look like. What does "domain forward record" actually mean, how does that work? I am not aware that this is a standard term. I know of DNS records (A records, AAA records and CNAME records usually), but it is unclear if that is what you refer to. Also whether you can implement rewriting rules in the host serving "mydomain.co". Such rules are not ontent, they can be implemented in the actual host configuration. But that depends on your hosting service.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  Let me explain.  I have one domain name at GoDaddy.  They have a feature they call domain forwarding.  I set that up and just put in the url to heroku and it just worked.  It even works with the UrlRewrite I put in my post.  As for the other records at GoDaddy they are just the godadddy defaults.  The other domain is registered at NameCheap.  They are the ones that have a dns record called "Url Redirect" like you, no idea what that does. No other DNS records set at NC. NC told me to forward the domain to heroku, all I needed was the url redirect record.

Comment: BTW, that is why I thought it was my rewrite rule.  One works and one does not.  I thought it was the rewrite rule because I am not familiar with how to write them and thought it may be wrong.

Comment: So if everything works, then what is your question? Sorry, I am lost.

Comment: The domain I redirect from GoDaddy using the rewrite rule posted works, but the redirect from namecheap using the same rewrite rule does not work.  So I am guessing, either the rewrite rule is wrong for all cases or the domain forward is different somehow and maybe that is because of the dns records. However, I am not sure what the dns records would have to do with the rewrite rule.  The forwarding is happening in both cases, but the rewrite rule works on one domain but not the other.

Comment: I'd say the question is what you actually mean by "rewriting". I am pretty sure that both companies know how to setup a DNS record. Or how to forward a request. The question is _how_ that is done which only you can answer. Either by checking the documentation or by testing. That is what I meant above with "how do the requests look like after that redirect"? What host is requested _after_ the redirection?

Comment: First off, thank you so much for trying to help, I know I am not very clear... sorry.  So I enter this into my browser, www.mydoamin.com and it takes me to mysd.herokuapp.com/public and shows the right page but the url in the browser shows mysd.herokuapp.com/public, I want it to show www.mydomain.co that is why I created a .htaccess file with the rewrite rule above.  So I guess the question is, is my rewrite rule wrong, or is it the dns records?

Comment: OK, that was more clear. Obviously an http redirection is returned to  request to "mydomain.com" telling the browser to load heroku instead. You can actually see that detail if you open your browser's console (typically F12, but that depends on your browser) in an anonymous browser window, the networking tab in there. If you then make a test request. A redirection will _always_ change the URL visible in the browser, that is the purpose of such redirection. You could try to _disable_ that redirection and implement your proxy rule instead. What happens then?

Comment: Basically you need to find out whether you can implement your proxy rule inside the http server that serves "mydomain.co". So there has to be an apache http server serving that host. And that is where the rule has to be implemented. A forwarding rule needs to be deactivated.